# How to write unit test case for POST/PUT/DELETE API in a flask application

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest

Lets say, there is one API, that actually takes input from the frontend , validates it and stores in the database. If I do functional testing, I can call the API directly, but it triggers/ inserts the actual payload to the database.

How do we figure out to write unit test?

I have searched about various libraries like monkeypatch, Mockito, and Python built-in mock and patch functions, but couldn't find enough / clear way to implement them.
Can someone take up time to give an example please

Comment: Try looking at [How to write unit test for django-rest-framework apis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904362/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-django-rest-framework-apis)

Comment: look at `unittest` or `pytest` libraries. you can find answer in their docs.

Comment: this can help: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/testing/
@greybeard

Comment: haha. sorry :) @Sai Naveen